# Is this a good practice of immutability?

Tags: c#, immutability

Good morning,

Suppose I have a class

```
public class Class
{
    int something;
    int[] otherThing;
}
```

and I want to make objects of type `Class` immutable. Suppose also that I have a very frequent operation which creates a new object of type `Class`,

```
public Class SomeFunction()
{
    int[] Temp = new int[] { ... };

    return new Class(1, Temp);
}
```

To avoid creating new objects too often, and since `Temp`is no longer accessible out of the method, is it too bad to set on the constructor

```
this.otherThing = Temp;
```

instead of

```
otherThing = new uint[Temp.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < Temp.Length; i++)
{
    this.otherThing[i] = Temp[i];
}
```

?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the constructor that does this is private its fine IMO. Since you know the content of the other array will never change you can directly use it. You could even share one instance of the array between several instances of your class if you want to without causing any problems.

A public constructor directly using a provided array is a bad idea on the other hand. Since that can be used to break immutability.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to assign a copy of `temp` to `otherThing` so that any changes to `otherThing` will not change `temp`. You can also use the [`Array.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copyto.aspx) method for this purpose.

In addition you should seriously consider using `IEnumerable<int>` or `IList<int>` instead of `int[]` because arrays by nature work against the idea of immutability. [Read this blog post by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx).

Comment: `otherThing` is a private field. So there is no reason to make that field `IEnumerable<int>` or `IList<int>`. When exposing the field you need to wrap it into a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` or pass through `GetEnumerator` in a way that hides the array. And since he can guarantee that the array he passes in will not change after being assigned to the field it is safe without a copy.

Comment: While that is true, why start with an array when the same job can be done by a safer data structure like IEnumerable<T> or a ReadOnlyCollection<T>. So basically why use a mutable data structure and depend upon a programmer to treat it as immutable?  How will other developers who will maintain\change this code in future will know that the array is supposed to be treated as immutable? Why not use an immutable sequence instead?

Comment: You always assume that whoever changes code inside the class itself knows what he is doing. And you should of course document that the array is immutable. And by itself `IEnumerable<T>` is just an interface and as thus neither mutable or immutable. That depends on the collection you use to back your interface. `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` isn't immutable either. If you know the `IList<T>` passed into it you can still change it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the first option you always get a new instance and in the second one all the created "Class"es will point to the same array (!). So if you change something in the array in any Class, all the other classes are changed.

Comment: -1. The fact that I know that is exactly the point why I am posing the question. Also, they will not point to the same array. They will point to the array which is passed as a parameter to the constructor, which is new everytime the method is called.

Comment: @Miguel: No, arrays are reference types, so they are passes and stored as references.

Comment: Well since you want it to be immutable I would say you'll need a new array (as posted above), unless you're 100% sure that the array won't change. But then it's a constant and you don't need to pass it everytime.